# WSO2 API Manager: Customizing the user profile GUI

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

I changed the user store to our custom oracle db. so, there are some fields that should be added to user profile when set the user profile of a user. How can I add some new properties to user profile GUI and map those to related fields in *um_user* table? thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0):

you may want to have a look in the administrative console ( /carbon ) for the claim management.

Locate claims in the claim dialect `http://wso2.org/claims`, there you can define additional user attributes and their attribute names (field name in the underlying userstore).

good luck

Comment: thanks, but when I enter the http://wso2.org/claims in browser I redirect to https://wso2.com/libraryclaims/ address and can not find the page!